# How to activate the // commentary on emacs

Tags: emacs

On my emacs I want to activate commentary when i put "//" at the begining of a C code line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `~/.emacs`

```
(require 'cc-mode)
(define-key c-mode-map "/"
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (if (not (looking-back "^/"))
        (self-insert-command 1)
      (insert "*  */")
      (backward-char 3))))
```

This will work only if you're at the actual beginning for C code line,
i.e. no indentation.
If you want indentation, change the regexp to `"^[ \t]*/"`.